# html audio tags not working in .php file

Tags: html, html5-audio

This is my code. I am trying to play audio file inside a .php file running it on xaamp server but the audio bar appears but is totally disabled please help

```
<audio controls>  
  <source src="ypousaf.mp3" autoplay />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
```

Comment: Where is the .mp3 file located? Is it in the same directory as this PHP file?

Comment: There is no PHP here.

Comment: yes it is in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

Mp3 file is supported by IE only.
To play audio files in other browsers you need to convert it in other formats

Here is the list of supported formats by different browsers.
You can find more at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Audio Formats and Browser Support
Currently, there are 3 supported file formats for the  element: MP3, Wav, and Ogg:

Browser MP3 Wav Ogg
Internet Explorer   YES NO  NO
Chrome  YES YES YES
Firefox NO
Update: Firefox 21 running on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, and Android now supports MP3 YES YES
Safari  YES YES NO
Opera   NO  YES YES

Here is the code i used ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<audio controls>  
  <source src="Ellie Goulding - Burn - YouTube.mp3" autoplay />
  Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>
<audio controls>
  <source src="Ellie Goulding - Burn - YouTube.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Works perfect in both extensions with firefox 29 and the mp3 file is only supported by firefox only.

Comment: but its working perfectly fine in .html the errors occur in .php extensionhttp #sky-kumar

Comment: Try using type attribute type="audio/mpeg"

Comment: I tried in my pc with .php and .html and found that ie and chrome are not supporting mp3 files but the information i provided you shows it supports those formats..

I tried it with Firefox 29 and it is working fine with both php and html extensions

I think the problem is with the browsers try switching browsers test it in it..
Different browsers support different audio formats so you need to convert a single file in to many formats.